# $\ell$-adic Representations of Finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

I am recently read the book "Theory of $p$-adic Galois Representations" written by Fontaine and Ouyang. (Here is the link to this book: [http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~yiouyang/galoisrep.pdf](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Eyiouyang/galoisrep.pdf))

Let $K:=\mathbb{F}_q$ be the finite field of characteristic $p$ with $q$ elements. Fix an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$, and denote the Galois group of $\overline{K}/K$ by $G_K$. The geometric Frobenius $\tau_K:\overline{K}\rightarrow \overline{K}$ of $G_K$ is $x\mapsto x^{1/q}$. If $\rho:G_K\rightarrow \text{GL}(V)$ is a finite dimensional continuous $\ell$-adic representation (this means $V$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-vector space), we write $u:=\rho(\tau_K)$. Then we have the following Proposition:

**Proposition.** (Prososition 1.10 in the book)
The eigenvalues of $u$ are all in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}^{\times}$. Conversely, given any $u\in \text{GL}(V)$, there exists a continuous homomorphism $\rho:G_K\rightarrow \text{GL}(V)$ such that $u=\rho(\tau_K)$ if all the eigenvalues of $u$ are in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}^{\times}$.

I have no idea how to prove this, although the authors say that it is easy.

I think the key point is how to determine the element $\rho(\tau_K^n)$ for $n\in \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$. In the book, they write $\rho(\tau_K^n)=\lim_{m\in \mathbb{Z}, m\mapsto n}u^m$, but I cannot understand what the limit means.

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, I know.

Comment: That’s what the limit means!

Comment: Oh, I got it. But how should I prove the proposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what the proposition says; it says that the eigenvalues are units. They don't have to lie in $\mathbb{Q}_l$.

Here's a hint. If an invertible matrix $M$ acting on $V$ has an eigenvalue which is *not* a unit, then, after possibly inverting $M$, we may assume it has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| > 1$. But then $M^{n}$ for large $n$ will have an eigenvalue $\lambda^n$ where $|\lambda^n|$ is getting bigger and bigger.

Now you have to understand (given the structure of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$) why continuity of $G_K \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ implies that there will be some big integral $n$ such that $M^n$ and $M^0 = I$ are as close as you wish linear maps, and this will preclude the eigenvalues of $M^n$ being big.

Comment: So it seems that I make a mistake that $\{ x\in \mathbb{Q}_{\ell} \mid |x|_{\ell}=1 \}=\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{\ell}$; however, the two sets are not the same.